# Calling wordpress previous_post_link function with an html link

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In the midst of Customizing my new Wordpress site I would like to add next and previous portfolio post buttons to the single portfolio post page, and I've found that I can easily do so by pasting the following code:

```
<div><?php previous_post_link('%link', 'PREV'); ?> | <?php     next_post_link('%link', 'NEXT'); ?></div>
```

Somewhere in the single-flv_portfolio.php page.

The only problem with this solution though is that I'm only able to place the links/buttons in the "portfolio frame" so to speak, and not in the actual content of every single post, which I would like to, for layout purposes.

I've tried pasting the same code within the contents of a portfolio post, using the backend editor, but to no avail. Wordpress, or my specific template (Wizard) seams not allow me using php at all - not even for something small like echoing out the current year in a dynamic copyright function.

**Is it possible to maybe create the next and previous portfolio post functions in a custom .php-file, and then call them with an html anchor tag, and if so, how would I go about doing that?**

Comment: You should be able to add code to a post but you may need to switch tabs at the top right of the textfield of the post. Did you try that?

Comment: A better way might be to use `add_action('the_content', 'my_content_function');` or something like `add_action('wp_footer', 'my_footer_function');`

Comment: I'm able to add HTML code using the text mode instead of the visual one, but php doesn't seem to work. I've read up on the matter and found that you can only add php into the content through the help of shortcodes.

Your solution seems interesting though, I'm a beginner when it comes to php, but I can kind of see where you're getting at. Care to elaborate? Thank you.

Comment: Another way would be to search wordpress.org for a 'php code in post' plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this in your functions.php file:

```
function my_next_previous_link($content) {
    $content .= 'some html here'; 
    return $content;
}

add_action('the_content','my_next_previous_link');
```

Comment: First of all I want to thank you for your tip about using a php code pasting plugin - insert php https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/ really did the trick for me, and it's super easy to use for a novice like me.

If you don't mind I would like to discuss this solution also, although the problem essentially is solved. Looking at the function is seems like it takes any HTML (or php?) of my liking and inserts into the actual post, after and appended to the content which is added through the wordpress UI. Is that assumption correct?

Comment: I like it, but just to clarify - if I would like total control of exactly where in the content, the buttons would be placed, inbetween an image and a text block for example, this wouldn't work, right?

Comment: Your assumption is correct. There are just many ways to handle this. You could create your own shortcode, which you can use in your post, you could create a javascript/jQuery script to handle things. It really depends on your scenario, most important, should it be in the exact same spot for all posts or do you want flexible placement. Go with what works first, familiarize yourself with the system and see if you want to change what you have.

Comment: Ok - That sounds like great advice! I'm also going to bend the rules a little bit by using this commenting section to thank you for your help, as well as accepting this answer as a solution. Even, though this very code is not going to be what I'm going to finally end up with, I feel that it's straighten things out to the point where it's practically a solution.